Does SE have a platform where asking for advice regarding prost grad applications would be on topic?
I am currently looking at MSc courses in financial mathematics, etc and had some questions about applying. I am assuming that the Quant SE is not the right place to ask these sorts of questions.
Does SE have a platform where such questions would not be off-topic?

There are many stacks and I don’t know them all but depending on the question you might take a look at our sister site Academia. Be sure to check their tour to verify that your question is on-topic.
To get the best advice I would advice to ask someone (an alumnus, an acquaintance or someone from your university) that knows your situation and the field. The specifics of your situation will always make this type of question a bad fit for the StackExchange-network.
